# Software to record video lectures on Linux

Tags: linux, video, youtube, video-recording

I am going to make some video sermons (or call them lectures) about Bible and put it on YouTube (or are there any good alternatives to YouTube?)

I use Linux. Currently the only video recording software I know is Cheese. But Cheese does not support annotating the video with titles (such as Bible quotes).

Note that I am not going to make live shows right now, only recordings. Live show may be an option in the future.

I also want if possible to add hyperlinks and/or images with hyperlinks (such as homepages of my books, donation request, etc.) to my video. Which software can do it?

Answer (score 3):

VLC can also record from your webcam or other video device (capture card, etc), either command line or via GUI.

There is also gtkRecordMyDesktop but I'm not sure if it could keep up with live video and audio and keep it all synched together if you were to bring up a window that simply monitored your webcam and recorded that.

As Steve Barnes' answer said, you'll also want to look at doing post-production work, which is where you'll be able to add a templated intro/ending, insert still images to display for N seconds, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) can capture video from a WebCam or other video source and there are a number of GUIs to control it with.

Not to directly record the videos but to annotate and add to your videos in post production take a look at [Movie Py](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/). You can use it to:

- Mix & Combine videos
- Add Annotations
- Add Titles & Subtitles
- Add special effects & lots more.
- If you have a regular set of operations to perform, e.g. Adding title, copyright, donation information then this could easily be scripted.

Both work on Linux, *(and Windows/OS-X)*, and are free and open source. There is no really reliable mechanism for embedding links into videos - the usual practice is to have a few seconds of frames at the end of the video &/or a subtitle with it in.  To save people having to type in the link you could consider including a QR code, (the python [qrcode](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode) library can produce one for moviepy to add).

Comment: What you suggest are command line utilities. Despite I know command line and Python programming, I'd want to consider a GUI program. Ideally this program could provide a template, which could for example add a PDF files with donation link at the end of every video. Can this be done with a GUI? or only with command line?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/44358243/856090 for my question about how to use FFMPEG

Answer (score 1):

Hi Proton I would suggest Open Broadcaster Software and here are 3 reasons why.[image: 3 reasons why]

1. You want to try different live hosting vimeo, hitbox, youtube
2. It's simple to annotate or use green screening (Chroma keying) to capture attention.
3. you can display donation hyperlinks and use live chat to drive more donations.
   https://obsproject.com